# How to regenerate table contents using Ajax & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 and I have retrieved the list of `users` at a table in blade:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="contentDiv">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>User Status</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach($users as $user)
          <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->status }}</td>
      @endforeach
</table>
```

And this is my Controller method:

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::query();

        if(request('desc') == 1){
             $users->orderBy('id','DESC');
        }else{
             $users->orderBy('id','ASC');
        }

        $users = $users->latest()->paginate(20);

        return view('admin.users.all', compact('users'));
    }
```

Then I tried adding a select option that can change the table order:

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="dropdown-list">
     <option value="asc" selected="selected">Ascending</option>
     <option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select>
```

So for example if user clicks on `Descending` option, an ajax request must change the table order from `asc` to `desc`.

And here is my try on Ajax:

```
   $("#dropdown-list").on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();

        if(val == "desc") {
            $.ajax({
                url: baseurl + '/admin/users?desc=1',
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    val: val,
                },
                jsonType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#contentDiv tr").remove();
                    // populate new data and append to table
                }
            });
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                url: baseurl + '/admin/users',
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    val: val,
                },
                jsonType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#contentDiv tr").remove();
                    // populate new data and append to table
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

So I try removing the entire table contents and after that I should populate the new data (`$users`) and append them to table.

How can I do that?

### Update 1

**`UserController.php`**:

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::query();

        if(request('desc') == 1){
            $users->orderBy('id','DESC');
        }else{
            $users->orderBy('id','ASC');
        }

        $users = $users->latest()->paginate(20);

        return response()->json([
            'users' => $users
        ]);
    }
```

And this is my blade template:

```
    @push('scripts')
        var environ = window.location.host;
        var index = environ.includes("localhost");
        if (index) {
            var baseurl = "{{ URL::to('/') }}";
        } else {
            var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
        }
        var environ = window.location.host;
        var index = environ.includes("localhost");
        if (index) {
            var baseurl = "{{ URL::to('/') }}";
        } else {
            var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
        }
    
            $("#dropdown-list").on('change', function(){
                var val = $(this).val();
    
                if(val == "desc") {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: baseurl + '/admin/users?desc=1',
                        type: 'get',
                        data: {
                            val: val,
                        },
                        jsonType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#contentDiv').find('tbody').html('');
                            response.users.forEach(refill_table);
                            function refill_table(item, index){
                                $('#contentDiv').find('tbody').append(`
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>${item['id']}</td>
                                        <td>${item['name']}</td>
                                        <td>${item['email]}</td>
                                <td>${item['status']}</td>
                                </tr>
                                    `);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                        url: baseurl + '/admin/users',
                        type: 'get',
                        data: {
                            val: val,
                        },
                        jsonType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#contentDiv').find('tbody').html('');
                            response.users.forEach(refill_table);
                            function refill_table(item, index){
                                $('#contentDiv').find('tbody').append(`
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>${item['id']}</td>
                                        <td>${item['name']}</td>
                                        <td>${item['email]}</td>
                                                        <td>${item['status']}</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                `);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    @endpush
    
    @component('admin.layouts.content' , ['title' => 'Users Lists'])

    <div class="card-tools d-flex">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 50%;" id="dropdown-list" name="select">
                <option value="asc" selected="selected">Ascending</option>
                <option value="desc">Descending</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
        
        <table class="table table-hover" id="contentDiv">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            @if($users->count() != 0)
                @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->status }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <td colspan="10" class="text-center">Nothing to show</td>   
            @endif  
    @endcomponent
```

Comment: You could create a route and controller method that outputs the table (complete HTML). Then instead of returning JSON call that route and replace the whole table with the AJAX response.

Comment: Another alternative would be to only get the data using JSON and render the table using JS. Then when the user want to change the order, you just sort the JSON you got in the beginning and re-render the table. No need to burden the server with an extra request if the only difference with the data is the order of the items.

Comment: @M.Eriksson That seems to be the best way, would you mind tell me how as an answer please...

Comment: I'm no JS guru and I don't know what you already know or where in that flow you're stuck. I recommend that you do some research into this. It's a pretty common pattern so there's definitely some guides/tutorials out there. Break it down: 1. Make an ajax request to get data. 2. Render the table from json. 3. Sort JSON. 4. Re-render the table.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Ok just tell me I should return it like this or not: `return response()->json($users);`

Comment: If that gives you an array of user objects, then sure.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Hello sir, I just used the `return response json` in my Controller but the problem is not fixed yet. I added my whole codes as **UPDATE #1**, would you mind check it out and help me out with this, I'm really stuck with this :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html should look like this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->status }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Then you will need to empty table body in ajax success like:

```
$('#contentDiv').find('tbody').html('');
```

And then you have to foreach over response array

```
response.users.forEach(refill_table);
function refill_table(item, index){
    $('#contentDiv').find('tbody').append(`
        <tr>
            <td>${item['id']}</td>
            <td>${item['name']}</td>
            <td>${item['email]}</td>
            <td>${item['status']}</td>
        </tr>
    `);
}
```

When it comes to your controller you should send json response like:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::query();

        if(request('desc') == 1){
            $users = $users->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(20);
        }else{
            $users = $users->orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(20);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'users' => $users
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand, you mean I have to return the response as json? Then where to return the blade view ?

Comment: Can you please provide me the whole `index` method of Controller, including the returned response as json

Comment: You don't have to return response to any page if will return response to the page from where request submitted. Check edited answer please. And I recommend you to read more about request and return types. Because you should use `post` request for that kind of operation.

Comment: Let me know if it helped you out. If it was, you have to accept answer

Comment: No I couldn't fix this problem, I added whole my code at Controller & Blade including the ajax part, would you check it out please...

Comment: You don't have tbody tag in html. It should be between if and foreach statements

Comment: Man the problem is not related to tbody tag! The whole process should be done differently

Comment: There are so many ways to do it and I already mentioned one. But we can't teach you "WHOLE" process. Try to search it in youtube or smth

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli - _"Because you should use post request for that kind of operation"_ - Why? GET is for _getting_ data (which is what they are doing) and POST is for sending data to be stored/change some state on the server (which is not what they are doing)